# TI DM368 access via JTAG with openocd or jlink commander

Tags: jtag, bootloader, openocd, nand-flash, j-link

I have a board with a TI DaVinci TMS320DM368 processor. It users a NAND to boot from for its Linux operating system. The bootloader in the NAND appears to have become corrupt and can no longer boot. The board has a UART, but I can't boot from that, so I am looking into the possibility of using the JTAG port to either write to the NAND or to inject and run a bootloader on the CPU. The latter of these options would then allow me to use some of the native tools on Linux to write the bootloader back to the NAND.

The issue that I am having is that I am unable to connect to the DM368 via either Openocd or Jlink (also tried Jflash). There appears to be very little documentation relative to this process for this processor, as well as a lack of config files to support this processor for either product. There appears to be several for the DM365, but they don't work for this chip.

I was hoping that someone out there might have worked with this product in the past and know an effective way to do what I'm trying to do with the tools I am using, or other tools that I would be able to get.

Thanks in advance for any advice or assistance.